# Travelling tinkerer between towns along a river dynamic prorgramming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

I need some help thinking up a potential dynamic programming solution in pseudocode for the following problem.

A travelling tinker, lives along a wide river. Travelling to various towns along the left bank of the river to make a living for themself. They stay in a town for a day or more or simply pass through the town. If they decide to stay in the town for work they need to wait a couple of days before their workers permit is accepted. Each town takes a different amount of time for a permit to come through.

The tinkerer knows roughly how much they can make from working in a town for a day for each day. They need to decide which towns they travel to and work in to maxmimise their revenue.

Everyday the tinkerer decides whether to simply work in their current town (assuming their permit has been accepted) or travel to an adjacent town. It always takes two days to travel between towns. Due to the wdith of the river cross is difficult so each town is consider top have two adjacent towns, except for the twi towns at the ends of the river which only have 1.

Conditions:
there are n towns

In two days the tinker can travel from town i to either town i+1 or i-1. From town 1 they can only travel to town 2 and from town n can only travel to town n-1

money is a list of lists. each interior lists are length n. each interior list represents a different day. money[a][b] is the revenue the tinker makes working in city b on day a

permit is a list of non-negative ints, permit[i] is the number of days town i requires the tinker to wait before their permit is approved

base is an int 1 - n, representing the town the tinker starts in. They can work start working in the town without needing permit approval from day 1. If they leave and return they will need to wait for approval again.

Output:
the max revenue that the tinker can earn as an integer

Example:

```
revenue = [
[1, 6, 7, 4]
[2, 9, 4, 11]
[3, 12, 15, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[4, 5, 7, 3]

permit = [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Could someone please give me some advice on a potential approach to solving this. At the moment I'm think that a bottom-up approach suits best and that we are looking at a situation where we are looking for the maximum starting from the final day, but I'm having some trouble figuring it out

Answer (score 1):

let dp[t][i] be max revenue if tinker stays in town i at day t

then, dp[t][i] = max(dp[t-1][i-1], dp[t-1][i+1], dp[t-permit[i]][i] + revenue[t][i])